# Calling python argument inside string

Tags: python, string

I want to call python argument inside string. Is that possible?
Suppose I have declared variable mypath as

```
mypath = os.path.abspath('1.jpg')
```

and I need to call it inside another variable that is string like following

```
cmd0 = 'gimp-console-2.8 -b -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys,os;sys.path=[\'.\']+sys.path;import mycode;'
cmd1 = 'mycode.doit('THIS VARIABLE MYPATH SHOULD GO HERE')"'
cmd2 = '-b "pdb.gimp_quit(0)"'
cmdfinal = cmd0 + cmd1 + cmd2
os.system(cmdfinal)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean... you can use the value in a number of ways, including `"using file %s" % mypath`.

Comment: What do you mean by "call it"? Or by "argument"? While it's possible to pass a function or other callable object as an argument, your example isn't doing anything remotely similar. Show us the code that you want to write (with a `# I'm stuck here` line) and explain what it shoul ddo.

Comment: Explained a little better now.

Comment: OK, better. Are you just trying to insert the string into `cmd1`? If so, the simplest way is `cmd1 = 'mycode.doit({0})'.format(mypath)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you want to do is insert a variable into the middle of a string.

This is done with string formatting. Python has a couple different ways of doing it, but the simplest is the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method, as explained in the tutorial section [Fancier Output Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting):

```
cmd1 = 'mycode.doit({0})'.format(mypath)
```

if `mypath` is, say, the string `/Users/me/Documents/1.jpg`, then `cmd1` will be the string `mycode.doit(/Users/me/Documents/1.jpg)`.

But that's not quite right, because you're trying to format a command that can be run by another Python interpreter. So, you want not just the contents of the string, but a Python literal for the string. How do you do that?

The [`repr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) of a string is the string in quotes, with proper escaping to make sure it can be used directly in Python code. (This isn't true for all objects; for example, some will return something like `<Spam object at 0x12345678>`, which isn't particularly useful; it's generally only true for objects where typing the output into Python code would make sense, and get you an exactly equivalent object.)

So, how do you get that? As explained in [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), you use the `r` conversion specifier:

```
cmd1 = 'mycode.doit({0!r})'.format(mypath)
```

Now, `cmd` will be the string `mycode.doit('/Users/me/Documents/1.jpg')`

And that's exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You do use a tuple

```
mypath = os.path.abspath('1.jpg')
cmd = 'gimp-console-2.8 -b -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys,os;sys.path=[\'.\']+sys.path;import mycode;mycode.doit(\'%s\')" -b "pdb.gimp_quit(0)"' % (mypath)
os.system(cmd)
```

Or using a format string

```
mypath = os.path.abspath('1.jpg')
cmd = 'gimp-console-2.8 -b -idf --batch-interpreter python-fu-eval -b "import sys,os;sys.path=[\'.\']+sys.path;import mycode;mycode.doit(\'{0}\') -b "pdb.gimp_quit(0)"'.format(mypath)
os.system(cmd)
```